# Set Identification: 2017 set, 4 bags

Tags: set-identification

Can anyone help identify which set these bags come from?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Based on the [60608 window shutter](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=60608) and the 8x8 plate in azure, this is set [11015 "Around the world"](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=11015-1).

[image: set image]

Comment: Unfortunetly, the pieces are different

Comment: @Denyria Care to elaborate? I gave a cursory look at the parts list for set 11015 and it seems to contain the parts visible in your photograph, at least the two bigger bags.